# Handling shared properties in TypeScript

Tags: data-structures, properties, typescript

I have a class system as shown below. And I would like to get the shared properties out/optimized toward a more maintainability data-structure.

My first thought was using an interface, but they can't contain properties in TypeScript (as far as I know). - So do you have any idea to how I can make this better?

```
class Particle {
    position: Vector;
}

class Block extends Particle {
    height: number;
    width: number;
    get Left(): number {
        return this.position.getX();
    }
    get Right(): number {
        return this.position.getX() + this.width;
    }
}

class Sphere extends Particle{
    radius: number;
    get Left(): number {
        return this.position.getX() - this.radius;
    }
    get Right(): number {
        return this.position.getX() + this.radius;
    }
}
```

Comment: What you have is what I would do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TypeScript you can use classes as interface definitions. You can introduce a class `LeftRight` that has the properties `Left` and `Right` and use this as the class definition:

```
class Block extends Particle implements LeftRight {
    /*  .... */
}
```

A fully working example can look like this:

```
class Vector {
    getX (): number { return 0; }
}

class Particle {
    position: Vector = new Vector();
}

class LeftRight {
    get Left(): number {
        throw 'Member Left not overriden';
    }
    get Right(): number {
        throw 'Member Right not overriden';
    }
}


class Block extends Particle implements LeftRight {
    height: number;
    width: number;
    get Left(): number {
        return this.position.getX();
    }
    get Right(): number {
        return this.position.getX() + this.width;
    }
}

class Sphere extends Particle implements LeftRight {
    radius: number;
    get Left(): number {
        return this.position.getX() - this.radius;
    }
    get Right(): number {
        return this.position.getX() + this.radius;
    }
}

var block = new Block();
block.height = 100;
block.width = 100;

// note that you can safely cast to type LeftRight
var lr: LeftRight = block;
alert('Left: ' + lr.Left + ' Right: ' + lr.Right);
```

This is also shown in the TypeScript handbook in the Mixin example: http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#mixins

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. - Thanks a lot!!. =)
Didn't new about mixins, so great to get introduced to something new.